# get data from firebase cloud firestore in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a blank page when trying to execute the following code to get data from firebase cloud firestore.

firebase.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
})
var db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export { db };
```

Code to get data from firebase cloud firestore:

FormStatus.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
class FormStatus extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { forms: [], }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        db.collection('form').get().then(snapshot => {
            this.setState({ forms: snapshot })
        })
    }
    render() {
        const { forms } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {forms.forEach(doc => {
                    return <p key={doc.id}> {doc.name}</p>
                })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default FormStatus;
```

I am able to post data in cloud firestore, but not able to get data back from it.

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach` method on Array always returns undefined, use `.map` instead, so you get the element array

Comment: Yeah, use `map()` instead

Comment: `{forms.map(doc => { return <p key={doc.id}> {doc.name}</p>})}` , like this? @GayatriDipali @Jerryc

Comment: @Jerryc `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): forms.map is not a function` I am getting this error

Comment: console.log snapshot to see what it is, it need to be an array to make .map to work

Comment: Please attach the output of the main objects you are working with`console.log(forms)`